# Accessing headers from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, http-headers, sinatra

I am trying to access the headers in a filter in sinatra. My request includes the header "HTTP_AUTH", however I can't access it. My filter is

```
before do
    halt 403 unless request['HTTP_AUTH'] == 'test'
end
```

It works correctly from my rack test.

```
browser.get '/mypath', "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json", "HTTP_AUTH" => 'test'
```

But when I try from other sources I can't access it. If I `puts request.env` I can see the token is in the request, but I can't access it.

```
"HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"close", 
"HTTP_AUTH"=>"test", 
"HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"application/json",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try use `before` block with `headers` method:

```
before do
  headers "HTTP_AUTH" => "test"
  headers "Content-Type" => "text/html; charset=utf-8"
end
```

or in request:

```
get '/' do
  headers['HTTP_AUTH'] = "test"
  headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=600'
  puts headers # show headers on this request
end
```

Use [`headers`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Helpers#headers-instance_method) with is just `hash`

Comment: Would this not set the headers? I'm trying to read the headers.

Comment: reading the `headers` method with no arguments did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

I just wanted to add that if you use `headers` it will not show custom headers. For example, I set up a custom header named X-CSRF-Token which I send on every AJAX request, and this one won't show up in that hash. If you need to access custom headers, you will find them through `request.env` like:

```
post '/' do
  header_token = request.env["HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN"]
end
```

(Notice how rack changes X-CSRF-Token to HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN)

Comment: Why does it do that?  Thanks for this I was wondering where my headers had gone